# 3 different flavors of apps(app bundle) signed with same app signing key displays same language content

Tags: android, bundle, signing

We have an android app with 3 different flavors in regional languages of which English variant is published as app bundle and is working perfect.Recently tried to release Hindi and Tamil variants of the same app signed using same app signing key.When both these apps are downloaded from Beta release,it shows English contents instead of Hindi and Tamil respectively.The primary language issue is found in app bundle only.Can anyone help me with this issue.

I have tried uploading an apk file instead of app bundle to troubleshoot the issue.Surprisingly apk is working without any flaw.

Comment: Usually this problem appears when you change language in runtime. App bundle was designed to handle automatically such things, meaning that all you need to do is build your bundle and sign it, before you had to build multiple apks and sign them yourself.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your reply.Yes we do change the language at runtime. Are you saying like-app language will be served from build flavor by default??We don't have to do anything manually?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you change language in runtime. The solution to your problem is to avoid the apks being splited in bundle, this can be achieved by adding the following to your app build.gradle:

```
android {
    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
    }
}
```

This ensures that in one generated APK you will have all the languages, witch is necessary when you change languages at runtime.